# link_to anchor for JS Table of Contents

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a show view with

```
<div><%= simple_format @chapter.body, id: "toc-container" %></div>
```

with some JS

```
<script> 
  $headings = $("h2, h3");
  $.each($headings, function(index, value){
    $("#toc-container").append("<li>" + $(value).html() + "</li>");
  });
</script>
```

The code creates the list for h2 and h3 headers, above the chapter.body.

How does one make the list link_to anchor for each header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery to generate the TOC, you can as well use it to generate the anchor links by extending your JS just a little bit:

```
<script>
  $headings = $("h2, h3");
  $.each($headings, function(index, value){
    $(value).attr("id", index);
    $("#toc-container").append(
      "<li><a href=\"#" +
      index + "\">" + $(value).html() + "</a></li>"
    );
  });
</script>
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janklimo/omyxvhtg/).**